# htmlspecialchars(); don't work

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars

When I use "htmlspecialchars" in this code:

```
<?php
$test = htmlspecialchars("<a>w3s.com</a>");
echo $test;
?>
```

I want see HTML entites, such as:

```
&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert - for example.
```

But I see this:

```
<a>w3s.com</a>
```

And in browser HTML markup doesn't display HTML entites.
Please help. Thank
(Sorry if my sentense building of words building are spooky.)

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars("<a>w3s.com</a>"))`?

Comment: Thank's. This method is simply than others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the browser to display the special characters you should write something like this:

```
<?php
$test = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", 
    htmlspecialchars("<a>w3s.com</a>")));
echo $test;
?>
```

Output: `&lt;a&gt;w3s.com&lt;/a&gt;`

This way you escape the special characters in order to let the browser draw them

If you want to see HTML entities rendered by the browser just write the HTML code, like this:

```
<?php
$test = '<a href="http://w3s.com">Enter here</a>';
echo $test;
?>
```

Output: [Enter here](http://w3s.com/)

I think you forgot to put the `href` attribute and so it didn't display it as an anchor. For more info visit [this w3schools' article](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: Thank you. It work.  But if I want that code in address line convert in HTML entites I write:
    `<?php
$test = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", 
    htmlspecialchars("<a>w3s.com</a>")));
echo $test;
?>`  But it doesn't work. Please help me again.

Comment: I got it now. I think you just forgot to put the 'href' attribute. I edited the post, check if that solves your problem

Comment: No. I want that when I put in address line harm code. He must convert in  chars like this: `&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert`

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was not working too, but you can see in the client(js):

```
echo "<script>console.log('" . htmlspecialchars("<a>w3s.com</a>") . "');</script>";
```

Browser console output:

```
&lt;a&gt;w3s.com&lt;/a&gt;
```

I mean i don't know how show it in the server side(php). Unless you nest twice the function call.

Answer (score -1):

What about using [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) instead of htmlspecialchars?